# Array functions removed from MozJS-91, causing issues with MongoDB 6.0?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I recently upgraded to MongoDB 6.0 and encountered some issues with certain array functions in MozJS-91. It seems that Mozilla has removed these functions, but I couldn't find any clear documentation explaining the reasons behind this change.

Could someone explain why these array functions were removed,

mongoDB [deprecation notice](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/release-notes/6.0-compatibility/#std-label-6.0-js-engine-change)

Comment: I’m not sure what’s unclear about the documentation you link to. The ***static*** versions of those functions appear to have been non-standard, and thus been deprecated and removed. Unless you used those functions statically (in an already non-standard way), this should hardly matter.

Comment: @deceze Yes you are right, i think i was confusing the static versions with the usual methods.